# Add border around an image view selectively

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have an image view on my Android UI. While I can add a border around it using a style, I need to be able to add a border selectively (so that it is only on the top and bottom or left and bottom or any other permutation from 1 to all 4 sides).

I've googled around to try and find a solution and most say go the style route (which I don't think will work in this instance).

Is there a way to add a border selectively around an UI element on android?

Comment: You can use insets for that in border.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="-3dp"
    android:insetRight="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

It will remove the left and right border of any view.